# MicW i456 or similar, works on Android smartphone?

Tags: field-recorder, portable-recorder, microphone, field-recording

Mmmm .. excuse my most awful English. Is just for fun, I don't expect professional results. I'm trying to find the best way to use my Xperia Neo smartphone as portable recorder conecting , for example, a battery powered microphone, or something like that. In internet there are many ways to do it in Iphone, but it seems to me that for android not

The smartphone's jack input is a TRRS conector, but i'm not sure of where the mic signal goes. I say that for make an adaptor, but i'm not sure.

Anyone has tried?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I partially answer myself. Useful page with information that may be valid for my answer. Maybe you will find it useful :

http://pinoutsguide.com/

For the SE smartphone headset pinout, maybe still working

http://pinouts.ru/HeadsetsHeadphones/sonyericssson_headset_pinout.shtml

Answer (score 1):

I tried MicW i456 on my Samsung Galaxy I9100.It works perfectly. It do not need any accessaries. Simply plug i456 into the earphone connector.